# Execute method from another python file with argues

Tags: python, methods, subprocess, execution, sys

I'm a python begginer and I wanted to execute a method (A) with argues that will call another method (B) that will return values to (A).
I only can't reached the (B) method directly, for this I used a main. And so I can't retrieve (B)'s informations from (A)
My architecture looked like this :

---

```
Main Folder
|-> test_caller.py (A)
|-> called_file.py (B)
```

---

I want to call a method with argues from test_caller.py (main method), that will execute method to called_file.py (function_called()), and I want that function_called() method return flag or value if it's possible.

---

test_caller.py :

```
import sys 
import subprocess
import os

def main():
    #method can't return something
    # my_path = os.path.join(os.path.abspath(__file__+"/../"),"test.py")
    # script_descriptor = open(my_path)
    # a_script = script_descriptor.read()
    # sys.argv = [my_path, "variable1","https://google.com"]
    # exec(a_script)

    my_path = os.path.join(os.path.abspath(__file__+"/../"),"test.py")
    #call function tes.py, but need a main method and so doesn't return the function value yet
    test = subprocess.run(['python',my_path,"variable1","https://google.com"],check=True)
    print(test)

if __name__ == '__main__':
    main()
```

---

called_file.py :

```
import sys
import requests
def function_called(variable,variable2):
    #Potato = Flag 
    try :
        potato = 0
        print(str(variable + " is ready to use "+ variable2 + " as variable number 2"))
        request = requests.get(variable2)
        if(request.status_code == 200):
            response = request.text
            return response
        else :
            potato = 1
    #Flag exception potato = 1 => failure
    except Exception as  exc :
        print("An error occured " + str(exc))
        potato = 1
    return potato

    #I want that main issue disappear, for returning potato method value (flag 0 or 1) to my method's calling
    # if __name__ == "__main__":
    #     function_called(sys.argv[1],sys.argv[2])
```

How could I do that ? Thanks for helping me.

Comment: Why would you use subprocesses instead of `import`s here?

Comment: Hello AKX, 
I wanted to use subprocess because after I will call dynamically other methods by the same kind of process. For better performance I was looking for something that hasn't to import all of files directly.

Comment: What do you mean with "call dynamically"?

Comment: By dynamically I mean that, after, a variable in my method (A) could point to other files (with just the path as object) like called_file(1) called_file(2) , etc

Comment: You can use [`importlib.import_module()`](https://docs.python.org/3.9/library/importlib.html#importlib.import_module) to import a module by name, if that's what you're saying.

Answer (score 0):

Hello AKX thanks for your help, this solution might be good for our program,
For those who's had a similar problem, the solution now is this:

on test_caller.py :

```
def main(): 
    test = importlib.import_module("called_file")
    object = test.function_called("tata","https://www.google.com")
    print(object) #do what you want from the returned object
```